# REVISITED: What is an open cover?

Tags: general-topology

What exactly is an open cover? Could someone explain it to me like I'm five, and then give a professional answer too?

---

Here is some literature that may be of interest to any onlooker curious about what an open cover is:

[image]

*Reference:* M.A. Armstrong's *Basic Topology*

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeVA74yivyg

Comment: A collection of open sets that collectively cover another set.

Comment: What is a finite subcover?

Comment: A subcover that is finite.

Comment: @anon, OMG, really? I mean what does finite mean explicitly? Are you an American, anon?

Comment: Ask a funny question, get a funny answer. A native English-speaking five-year old (perhaps a bit older) will probably be able to understand the concept of (possibly infinitely many) regions in space covering another region, and a finite number of those regions being sufficient to cover it as well, at least with some good visual aids.

Answer (score 15):

An open cover of a set $Y$ is a family, (collection), of sets that are open, (a set of open sets), such that $Y$ is a subset of the union of sets in that family. 
Of course when I say "open", I mean that these sets are included in some topology $\mathcal T$ on a space $X$, and $Y \subseteq X$. 
"Union up all the sets in the family", 
"If $Y$ sits inside of that union"
"Then that family is an open cover"

Comment: Is the empty set an open cover of the empty set? Are all sets an open cover of the empty set?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte The empty set is a subset of all sets so it is certainly a subset of itself. So I would say, "Yes", and "Yes".

Comment: It's a collection of open sets that covers another one, yes?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte Yep

Comment: Hey Rus,I don't think you have explained it to a five year old yet (Paul here, I should probably change my name).

Comment: So an open cover of $[0,1]$ could be $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\pmatrix{\frac{1}{n}-1,\frac{n+1}{n}+1}$?

Comment: @Rustyn Sure want to create a room, or google chat or something

Comment: @LoieBenedicte  $\{(-1,2)\}$ is also an open cover.

Comment: @LoieBenedicte Actually your open cover of [0,1] would be the set: $\{n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}: \left(\frac{1}{n}-1,\frac{n+1}{n}+1\right)\}$

Comment: @PaulPlummer I invited you to chat thru broncomail

Comment: I see, so the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\pmatrix{\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}}\}$ is not an open cover of $[\frac{1}{2},1]$, right?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte Yep it is "NOT" an open cover, because $1$ is not covered.

Comment: Is there an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte Of course, set the open cover $\mathcal O$ = $\{\mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: @PaulPlummer -- were you implying that you are 5 years old?  Or do you have a five year old kid who still doesn't understand this?

Comment: @BettyMock The question says to explain to the op like Loie was five years old

Comment: @BettyMock I was asking in the spirit of the following site: http://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/

Comment: This comment thread is going to infuriate the moderators of this website. I think this should be the last comment.

Comment: can Y be exactly that union? and does any subset has an open cover?

Answer (score 8):

Tommy has a bunch of toys, and Sally has some too, so does Kelly, and Johnny. Now Tommy, Sally, Kelly, and Johnny have *their favorite*$^1$ toys, you know because some of them they *don't like*$^2$. If we lay all of everybody's favorite toys on the floor, then we will definitely have *all the toys that Joey has*$^3$.

---

$1$: The interior of the set.

$2$: The boundary of the set.

$3$: The set which is covered by the union.

---

An open cover of a set $E$, in the metric space $\chi$, is a collection of sets $\{G_\alpha\}$ whose union "covers" (contains) $E$, and so, for example if you're given the set $E=\{[1,3]\}$ in the metric space $\chi=(\mathbb{R},d)$, where $d$ is the Euclidean metric, then provided the sets $G_1=\{(0,\frac{3}{2})\}$, $G_2=\{(1,\frac{5}{2})\}$, and $G_3=\{(2,4)\}$ we can say that $\bigcup G_\alpha$ covers $E$.

---

[image]

---

Above we see that $\{G_\alpha\}$, where $\alpha=1,\dots, 5$, is an open cover of $E$. The green lines denote openness. Note that all sets but $G_5$ are necessary to cover $E$, and as such the union of the sets $G_1, G_2, G_3$, and $G_4$ are a subcover of $\{G_\alpha\}$ as they cover $E$.

Comment: Do I have this idea down?

Comment: I just want to know if I used the language correctly to describe this idea, and if I'm using the notation correctly and what have you.

Comment: The picture looks good, I didn't read exactly what was written above it. The picture is exemplary... if all of those $G$'s are open.