# Compactness implies closedness

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness, separation-axioms

I was reading the post:

[How to prove that a compact set in a Hausdorff topological space is closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-prove-that-a-compact-set-in-a-hausdorff-topological-space-is-closed)

Quoting the accepted answer:

> Fix $x\in\mathbb{X}\setminus K$. Since $\mathbb{X}$ is Hausdorff, for
>   each $y\in K$ there are disjoint open sets $U_y$ and $V_y$ such that
>   $x\in U_y$ and $y\in V_y$. $\{V_y:y\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$,
>   so it has a finite subcover, say $\{V_y:y\in F\}$, where $F$ is some
>   finite subset of $K$. Let $$U=\bigcap_{x\in F}U_x\;;$$ clearly $U$ is
>   an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $K$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary
>   point of $\mathbb{X}\setminus K$, $K$ must be closed.

Why is $\{V_y \mid y \in K\}$ an open cover of $K$? I mean, to use compactness in the argument, we need that the set $V_y \subseteq K$, otherwise I don't see how it can be part of an open cover in the subspace $K$.

Comment: Where does $A$ come from?

Comment: Sorry, was meant to be $K$. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the $U_x\cap K$ if you insist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two different notions of compactness you're dealing with:  a compact subset of a topological space, and a compact space.  But indeed when there's overlap, there is no distinction.  That is,

> Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $K\subset X$ be given.  Then $K$ is compact (in the subspace topology) if and only if whenever $\{U_\alpha\}$ is a collection of open subsets of $X$ such that $K\subset\cup_\alpha K_\alpha$, there is a finite subset $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ of $\{U_\alpha\}$ such that $K\subset U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_n$.

The proof of this is quite straightforward, but a useful exercise if you're new to topology.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explains everything!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!

Comment: The proof indeed was quite straightforward. Thanks. Now, I can sleep without worrying :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace $V_y$ with $V_y\cap K$ and all will work:

- each $V_y\cap K$ is a subset of $K$;
- each $V_k\cap K$ is open in $K$;
- $\left\{V_y\cap K\,\middle|\,y\in K\right\}$ is an open cover of $K$.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking too. Does this mean that the proof given is wrong?

Comment: @Math_QED Not at all. It uses a diiferent way of defining open cover when $K$ is a subset of a topological space $X$: an open cover is a set $\mathcal A$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $K\subset\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A$. But this definition of open cover ledas to the same concept of compactness.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\{y\} &\subseteq V_y \\
K = \bigcup_{y \in K} y &\subseteq \bigcup_{y \in K} V_y
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. $V_y$ must be open in $K$, which means that they have to be a subset of $A$ in the first place

Comment: @Math_QED What is $A$?  It never appeared in the question.  Since each $V_y$ is open, the arbitrary union is also open.

Comment: @Math_QED Your question is "Why $\left\{V_y\cap K\,\middle|\,y\in K\right\}$ is an open cover of $K$", so I showed how $\bigcup_{y \in K} V_y$ [*contains*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/487889/290189) $K$, while assuming that you know that it's open.  In the definition for a Hausdorff space, $V_y$ is open in $\Bbb X$.

Comment: The accepted answer contains the cause of confusion. I upvoted your post btw. Thanks for the help.